# How to make a Kotlin Comparable Type?

Tags: kotlin

Just learning to define a DateRange type

```
val wholeYear2017 = Date(2017,1,1)..Date(2017,12,31)
```

So I created the type as below

```
class DateRange<Date: Comparable<Date>>(override val start: Date, override val endInclusive: Date)
    : ClosedRange<Date>

class Date (val year: Int, val month: Int, val day: Int) {

    operator fun compareTo(other: Date): Int {
        if (this.year > other.year) return 1
        if (this.year < other.year) return -1
        if (this.month > other.month) return 1
        if (this.month < other.month) return -1
        if (this.day > other.day) return 1
        if (this.day < other.day) return -1
        return 0
    }

    operator fun rangeTo(that: Date): DateRange = DateRange(this, that)
}
```

But I got a compile error

```
One type of argument expected for class DateRange<Date: Comparable<Date>> : ClosedRange<Date>
```

What did I missed? Did I do it correctly?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Is your question really about how to create a Comparable type?  Then just have your type implement the Comparable interface (override `compareTo`).

```
class Date(val year: Int, val month: Int, val day: Int) : Comparable<Date> {
    override operator fun compareTo(other: Date): Int {
        if (this.year > other.year) return 1
        if (this.year < other.year) return -1
        if (this.month > other.month) return 1
        if (this.month < other.month) return -1
        if (this.day > other.day) return 1
        if (this.day < other.day) return -1
        return 0
    }
 }
```

You don't need a `rangeTo` method because all `Comparable<T>` types have a `rangeTo` extension already defined. See [Ranges](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html#ranges) and [rangeTo](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/range-to.html#rangeto).  But, if you still want your own `DateRange` type (for other purposes), the simpler form of the `DateRange` class would be...

```
class DateRange(override val start: Date, override val endInclusive: Date)
    : ClosedRange<Date>
```

In other words, there is no need for the generic parameter on `DateRange`.

Then you would write your own `rangeTo` operator.  Either, add `operator fun rangeTo` to your `Date` class, or provide a root level extension function (my preference which is consistent with the Kotlin library approach).  Both will shadow/hide the `Comparable<T>.rangeTo` extension function for your `Date` type.

```
// class level rangeTo operator
operator fun rangeTo(that: Date) = DateRange(this,that)

// root level extension
operator fun Date.rangeTo(that: Date) = DateRange(this,that)
```

Comment: I can't do `class DateRange(override val start: Date, override val endInclusive: Date): ClosedRange<Date> `. It will complain `Type argument is not within its bounds: should be subtype of 'Comparable<Date>'`

Comment: So, that's the reason I use `class DateRange<Date: Comparable<Date>>(override val start: Date, override val endInclusive: Date) : ClosedRange<Date>` to solve the compilation error.

Comment: If you add `: Comparable<Date>` to your `Date` class, then your `DateRange` class does not need generic parameters.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks!!

Answer (score 46):

You need to implement `Comparable` interface. You can use `compareValuesBy` helper function:

```
data class Data(
        val a: Int,
        val b: Int
) : Comparable<Data> {
    override fun compareTo(other: Data) = compareValuesBy(this, other,
            { it.a },
            { it.b }
    )
}
```

Comment: That should be the accepted answer. By far the most elegant solution!

Answer (score 4):

You are almost there:

Firstly, you must make your class `Comparable`:

```
class Date (val year: Int, val month: Int, val day: Int): Comparable<Date> {
```

Secondly, you must specify the generic of the return type or just omit it (let the compiler infer it)

```
operator fun rangeTo(that: Date): DateRange<Date> = DateRange(this, that)
operator fun rangeTo(that: Date) = DateRange(this, that)
```

Comment: Thanks! I also need to add the `override` keyword to `fun operator compareTo`

Answer (score 1):

Straight from [Koans](https://kotlinlang.org/?_ga=2.100249626.565549113.1620241999-407406705.1610650382). I really encourage you to get to know the documentation first.

```kotlin
override fun compareTo(other: Date) = when {
        year != other.year -> year - other.year
        month != other.month -> month - other.month
        else -> day - other.day
    }
```

Comment: Comparing values by subtraction is susceptible to integer overflow: [Avoiding the Subtraction Trick (Baeldung)](https://www.baeldung.com/java-comparator-comparable#avoid-subtraction)

Answer (score 0):

You can translate date to the Integer representation using such formula, for example: year * 10000 + month * 100 + day.

```
class Date (val year: Int, val month: Int, val day: Int) {

    operator fun compareTo(other: Date): Int {
        return (this.year * 10000 + this.month * 100 + this.day) - (other.year * 10000 + other.month * 100 + other.day)
    }
}
```